# How can I minimize a quadratic matrix-valued function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider the following optimization problem
$$
\min_X \quad XAX^T + XB + B^TX^T \tag{1}
$$
where $X \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}, A \succ 0,$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$. To precisely define a solution $X^*$ of $(1)$, let $f(X) = XAX^T + XB + B^TX^T$. We say that $X^*$ solves $(1)$ if for every $Z \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ such that either $f(X^*) - Z \preceq 0$ or $f(X^*) - Z \succeq 0$ (i.e. $f(X^*)$ and $Z$ are comparable under the partial order $\preceq$), we have $f(X^*) - Z \preceq 0$, or equivalently $f(X^*) \preceq Z$.

According to a paper that I'm reading, the solution to the problem in $(1)$ is $X^* = -B^TA^{-1}$, which was derived by solving the equation
$$
2B^T + 2XA = 0 \tag{2}
$$
for $X$. It seems that $(2)$ is obtained by computing the Jacobian of the objective function in $(1)$ and setting it equal to $0$. However, I'm not sure if this is true, and even if it is, how to compute the Jacobian of the objective function in $(1)$. I would appreciate any hints on how the solution $X^*$ was obtained here.

Comment: What does it mean to minimize a matrix?

Comment: Since the given expression is matrix-valued, I assume he meant
$$ \min_X\; \left\|XAX^T + XB + B^TX^T\right\|_F^2 $$

Comment: Well, $X=0$ works for that, so there must be something more to it

Comment: @Karl I've added a more precise definition of a solution to the question.

Comment: So you want to choose $X$ so that $f(X)$ is negative definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A \succ 0$ then we can have its root square $CC^T = A$. Suppose that $A$ is not degenerate then $C$ is inversible.

$$\begin{align}
I &:= XAX^T + XB + B^TX^T \\
&= (XC)(XC)^T + XC(C^{-1}B) + (C^{-1}B)^T(XC)^T\\
&=\underbrace{(XC+(C^{-1}B)^T)\cdot (XC+(C^{-1}B)^T)^T}_{\ge 0} - \underbrace{(C^{-1}B)^T\cdot (C^{-1}B)}_{= B^TA^{-1}B}
\end{align}$$

The equality occurs if and only if $XC+(C^{-1}B)^T=0 \iff XA + B^T = 0 $.

*Remark:* You can denote $Y = XC$ and compute the Jacobian of $I$ with regard to $Y$ and obtain the same result.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding of your argument: Because the term $(C^{-1}B)^T\cdot (C^{-1}B)$ is independent of $X$, then we should only focus on optimizing the term $V(X) = (XC+(C^{-1}B)^T)\cdot (XC+(C^{-1}B)^T)^T$. However, because $V(X) \succeq 0$ for every $X$, then the smallest that $V(X)$ could be, in the sense of the partial order $\preceq$, is the $0$ matrix. Hence, we determine the value of $X$ such that $V(X) = 0$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @mhdadk Exactly. And to be more precise, the equality occurs if and only if $$XA + B^T = \mathbf{0}_{m \times n}$$ where $ \mathbf{0}_{m \times n} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ a matrix with all elements be $0$. And for more information, at the begining, I thought $I \in \mathbb{R}$ but it turns out that $I$ is a matrix. But the solution still holds true for that case.